# setInterval() function is working on console but data is not updating on browser after one api hit

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I have used a remote api to build own nodejs api.
I want to customer have hit my Node API instead of remote API to prevent load over on remote API.

A remote api have cricket score which is updating in every 30 sec so, i want to refresh the remote api in 30 seconds and update the data on my own node api without a hit .

So i have used setInterval() function on remote api.I have mentioned a code below.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const request = require("request");
const url = "http://cricscore-api.appspot.com/csa";

app.get("/getTeam/:id", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("content-type", "text/json");
  setInterval(function() {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const purl = url + "?id=" + id;
    request(purl, function(error, response, body) {
      console.log("error:", error);
      console.log("statusCode:", response && response.statusCode);
      console.log(body);
      res.end(body);
      console.log(res);
    });
  }, 30000);
});
```

Updated data from remote API reflected on console correctly with a one single hit. But when i check on my browser it is not updated.

Please help for that issue.

Comment: send periodic request from sever or for best practice use `sockets`

Comment: is any possible method to that thing on server side not on a client side?

Comment: @trincot I think OP wants to proxy to a 3rd party server when client requests something. To do this from client will result in many requests (if there are many clients) and the need for CORS. He can fetch the result from his express app and cache it for as long as he wants.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but it seems like when your request finishes all the memory allocated to your callback function for route handler gets destroyed causing setInterval to be removed.

The best way would be to write a cron job or scheduled task which will hit one of your own api url after specific time interval or specific time of your server whichever you prefer

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to get results only when requested and cache it for however long you need it:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const request = require("request");
const url = "http://cricscore-api.appspot.com/csa";
const requestAsPromise = url =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>
      request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        (error)
          ? reject(error)
          : resolve(body)
      })
    )
const requestAndCache = ((cache,activePromises) => howLong => url => {
  if(activePromises.has(url)){
    return activePromises.get(url);
  }
  if(cache.has(url) && (cache.get(url).lastCached+howLong)<Date.now()){
    return Promise.resolve(cache.get(url).response);
  }else{
    cache.delete(url);
  }
  activePromises.set(
    "url",
    requestAsPromise(url).then(response=>{
      cache.set(url,{response,lastCached:Date.now()});
      activePromises.delete(url);
      return response;
    })
  );
  return activePromises.get(url);
})(new Map(),new Map());

const cacheForThirtySeconds = requestAndCache(30000);

app.get("/getTeam/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const purl = url + "?id=" + id;
  cacheForThirtySeconds(purl)
  .then(
    result=>{
      res.setHeader("content-type", "text/json");
      res.end(result);
    }
  ).catch(error=>{
    console.log("what to do when there is an error?");
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
  })
});
```

Comment: @aviralgarg I corrected the code (was using purl instead of url in `requestAsPromise`). Can you please log the error? `console.log("what to do when there is an error?",error);`

Comment: Sorry as remote api data changes our api needs one more hit to reflect updated data

Comment: @aviralgarg Updated the answer, each url response needs to be stored and date when it's saved needs to be stored. You can also try to have a go at the middleware suggested by Jon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code isn't going to work for several reasons, the first being that you are trying to send multiple responses over a single connection. Once you call `res.end()` the response will be closed and no further content can be send over it.

The second reason is that you are putting the setInterval inside of the response handler, this means that for every request to this endpoint a new timer will be created.

What you want to do is create a sort of in-memory cache that uses the ID as a cache key and is kept for a certain amount of time. This way you can keep the response of the API in your server and send that as the response, and when you need to refresh the data you can reach out the API.

There is no real reason to build this yourself, as there are plenty of community established solutions available that can be used. Such as this `apicache` Express middleware: https://github.com/kwhitley/apicache

The resulting code would probably look something like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
const apicache = require("apicache");
const app = express();
const cache = apicache.middleware;
const url = "http://cricscore-api.appspot.com/csa";

app.get("/getTeam/:id", cache("30 seconds"), (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const purl = url + "?id=" + id;

  request(purl, (error, response, body) => {
    res.json(body);
  });
});
```